# jQuery removeClass and addClass within a function

Tags: jquery, function, this, addclass

I got following menu:

```
   <ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li>
     <a class="navitem active" href="javascript:loadTab();">My Profile </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="navitem search" href="javascript:loadTab();"> Search </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="navitem" href="javascript:loadTab();">Favorites </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

And my function (loaded in a .js file in the header):

```
function loadTab() {
    jQuery(".navitem").removeClass("active");
       jQuery(".navitem").click(function () {
          jQuery(this).addClass("active");
       });
}
```

Removing the class "active" works, adding the class "active" to the clicked element isn't working. Any ideas?

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As thatidiotguy said, you're removing the class in the wrong place.  You want something like this:

```
jQuery(".navitem").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery(".navitem").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Edit: And also, no need for the `javascript:loadTab();` in your `a` tags.  Change their `href` attributes to `#`:

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li>
        <a class="navitem active" href="#">My Profile </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="navitem search" href="#"> Search </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="navitem" href="#">Favorites </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also, I added `event.preventDefault();` in the `click` event handler for the links.

Comment: I got more stuff within this function that needs to be executed. I just moved the removeClass and addClass click outside my original function into the footer and it's working now, but I thought I could combine it wihtin this function.

Answer (score 0):

This is because whenever you click the tab, you are removing the class. You are then telling the tab to call loadTab, when it is clicked. This once again removes the class. Think Inception "Dream within a Dream"