# addClass and removeClass in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to give style to the current menu item which is clicked. For that i have added a class using jQuery. I used the following code for this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('#submenu li a').click(function() {  
        jQuery(this).addClass('current_menu');
    });
});
```

But when I click on another menu item,the class `current_menu` is not removed and the style stays as it is. I want to remove the style when clicked on another menu item. Please see http://itnews4india.com/. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery removeClass and addClass within a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198093/jquery-removeclass-and-addclass-within-a-function)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295982/jquery-addclass-removeclass-on-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you just add the class, but never remove the old versions.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('#submenu li a').click(function() {  

        // remove the old menu items class
        jQuery('.current_menu').removeClass('current_menu');   

        // add the new one
        jQuery(this).addClass('current_menu');
    });
});
```

Depending on the rest of your code, the selector in the removal might have to be adjusted to something like `#submenu li a.current_menu'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying that only

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
  jQuery('#submenu li a').click(function() {  
    jQuery("#submenu li a").removeClass('current_menu');
     jQuery(this).addClass('current_menu');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('#submenu li a').click(function() { 
        jQuery('a.current_menu').removeClass('current_menu'); 
        jQuery(this).addClass('current_menu');
    });
});
```

Third line in code will remove the `current_menu` class from the links, if they have already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#submenu li a').click(function() {
      // Remove class from all anchors inside list
      jQuery('#submenu li a').removeClass('current_menu');

      // Add class on selected/clicked anchor
      jQuery(this).addClass('current_menu');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#submenu li a').click(function() {  
            $('#submenu li a').removeClass('current_menu');
            $(this).addClass('current_menu');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thing is you have to remove the `class` before adding the one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('#submenu li a').click(function() { 
        jQuery('a.current_menu').removeClass('current_menu'); 
        jQuery(this).addClass('current_menu');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There also is a toggleClass function: [jQuery Api toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('#submenu li a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('current_menu just_menu');
};
```

Note that the element needs one of those classes initially!

Answer (score 1):

style `color` in `.current_menu`  is cover by `#submenu li a`

add   `#submenu li a.current_menu {color:#fff;}`  in your css

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery('#submenu li a').click(function() {
        jQuery('#submenu li').find('a').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass('current_menu');
        }) 
        jQuery(this).addClass('current_menu');
    });
});
```